# C# 32bit project under 64bit windows

Tags: c#, 64-bit, portability

I'm working on a form application, I use plenty of hardware, Wiimote, USBjoystick and serial port. It all worked fine under 32bit windows, but I had to upgrade to 64bit for some other apps I'm working on.

I did some research and it is possible to develop x86 apps under x64 system, but now I don't know if this is what I want. The trouble maker is obviously directX sdk. AFAICS another option is, to install a virtual x86 machine specificly for developing this app (I don't want dual boot). I've never used this before, so I'm kinda worried that all this hardware won't work under virtual machine.
I'm using [wiimoteLib](http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/releases/view/21997) and blueSoleil to connect bluetooth. So will this work. And do I use windows 7's virtual xp option, or a different virtual machine software? I'd probably use winXP as a virtual OS.

Comment: I don't understand the problem - x86 apps run perfectly well on x64

Comment: i have many 32 but apps that work on my windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I think you are better off attempting to get this to work and in the event you have a problem just post the details of any errors you are getting.  This issue is so specialized that it's the only way to get a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

32 bit applications run perfectly fine on 64 bit operating systems. I have lots of my applications developed for 32 bit and they run without any issues in 64 bit. As you say you have lots of hardware used we can't be sure which may work or may not work.

best solution is to run your app in 64 bit and see if anything is not working (I am sure 95% will work) and then come back here with specific questions.

Comment: When you say "run your app in 64bit" I think what you mean is, run the 32 bit version of the app on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: Oh. Yes sorry! that's what I mean.

Comment: Well, Serial comm works. I'm having problems with the part that uses the bluetooth device and the part with USB joystick. I think the problem is, that the installed dx_sdk includes x64 libs, but i'm trying to build x86 app which needs x86 libs. Could that be it?

Comment: I get the following error
System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
...

Comment: @delegate It's plausible that if the program was somehow linking against the 64 bit version of DX then you'd get an error like that. You really should have no trouble running a 32 bit app using DX on 64 bit Windows - I do that all the time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Inside IIS (7) click on Application Pools.
2. Find the Application Pool that is configured for your web application in the list.
3. Select it, then click Advanced Settings on the right.
4. Second setting in the list: Enable 32-Bit Applications - must be set to True.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling your application in Visual Studio, try setting the target platform to x86 rather than "any CPU" (Project options/build/target platform).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running a 32 bit app on a 64 bit development computer.  On VS 2010 I had to go to Properties/**Configuration Manager/New and choose x86**.  Then I did a clean and rebuild and it ran fine.